# Google Hangouts Video Playback Performance

Tags: video, google-chrome, google-hangouts

I've been trying to use Google Hangouts for video chat on my Ubuntu machines but the performance has been atrocious. My laptop is a Galago UltraPro from System 76 with an i7 and 16gb of RAM. My desktop is a ~3yr old AMD with Radeon 7xxx dedicated graphics card and 16gb RAM. Both computers experience extremely choppy playback of other users' video in Google Hangouts in Firefox, Chromium, and Chrome. Youtube playback is fine. The video being sent to other users is fine. I switched to a Windows 7 partition on my desktop and playback was completely fluid.

Has anyone else had performance issues with Hangouts in Ubuntu lately? Are there any known workarounds for poor video playback performance?